# Getting NULL instead the string value in soap request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I have a mobile application which communicates with my soap web service through ajax.

The user have to insert 2 fields to login (uname and password) and when he press the login
button, a javascript method is been called to post the data to the web service via ajax. 
I can get the input values from the html page, but when I debug the web service I see that the arguments that were received are null instead the values that the user entered, and I don't see why..

```
function login()
{
  var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
  var pass  = document.getElementById('password').value;


  var soapRequest =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"\
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
          <soap:Body>\
            <Login xmlns="http://service.webservice.org/">\
              <Name>' + uname + '</Name>\
              <Password>' + pass + '</Password>\
            </Login>\
          </soap:Body>\
        </soap:Envelope>';  

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",          
    url :  "http://localhost:8080/WebService/Service",          
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapRequest,

    success : function(data, status, req, xml, xmlHttpRequest, responseXML) 
    {
        var xmlText = $(req.responseXML).find('LoginResult').text();
        alert(xmlText);
            },
    error: function () 
    { 
        alert("error");
    }

});
```

Comment: > *I can get the input values from the html page*  Evidently not. Confirm those elements with those ids (`uname` and `password`) actually exist on the page.

Comment: they are found on the html page and i use "<script src = "jspage.."../>" to link the js function to the html page , so i can get the input values.. even if i use "alert" method after the 2 first lines of the login method, i can see the input values

Comment: i'm getting null even if i pass an hardcoded string instead the 'uname' and 'pass' parameters

Comment: Ah I see. You're getting null on the server, not the client. This is more of a "how to do soap from JavaScript" question.

Comment: Yes, this is the problrem.. and I dont know why.. the soap request  is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that we need to declare the namespaces of the method we call in soap request.

so after you deploy your web service to the server (glassfish or something else) it creates 
the WSDL file and each method has namespace.

so the soap request should be like that

```
var soapRequest =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"\
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
      <soap:Body>\
        <ns2:Login xmlns:ns2="http://service.webservice.org/">\
          <Name>' + uname + '</Name>\
          <Password>' + pass + '</Password>\
        </ns2:Login>\
      </soap:Body>\
    </soap:Envelope>';
```

ns2 is the namespace that was created by default, you can set your namespace by yourself